# Not able to Clean and Build in Netbeans 7.1 Beta

Tags: java, netbeans-7

While Doing clean and build i am getting following error. How to avoid this error.

```
Copying 1 file to E:\NIRAJ\Copyofcopyexample\build
E:\NIRAJ\Copyofcopyexample\nbproject\build-impl.xml:716: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\NIRAJ\Copyofcopyexample\nbproject\build-impl.xml:544: copylibs doesn't support the "rebase" attribute
```

This is the **build-impl.xml**

```
<copylibs compress="${jar.compress}" index="${jar.index}" indexMetaInf="${jar.index.metainf}" jarfile="${dist.jar}" manifest="@{manifest}" rebase="${copylibs.rebase}" runtimeclasspath="${run.classpath.without.build.classes.dir}">
```

I am using Windows 7,jdk 1.6. Previously i have compiled same code with Netbeans 6.9.1

Comment: Why do you use the Beta? The final version has been release about 6 months ago?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try deleting  **rebase="${copylibs.rebase}"** entry from the build-impl.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for reply, now i am able to build the project, Is this affect my business logic or any other component in my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Netbeans IDE, a simple solution would be `rebase="${copylibs.rebase}"`, move the referenced file imported and back to the original package, build the project. Remake the instance in the file and use the fix imports.